# All browsers crash on heavy websites, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, browser

Strange issue I've never ran into before - certain websites, usually those with heaveir loads or lazy loading, like Yahoo Mail, Youtube, even Gooogle Search, start crashing across all the browsers I have tested (Chrome, Firefox, Edge). This only happens on one PC, which means it's most likely a local Windows issues or something to do with the settings.

I'm not sure where to start looking for a possible solution, but I've tried clearing browser caches, data and reinstalling to no avail. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Example crash from Chrome:
[image: Example crash from Chrome]

Examples of a crash:

1. Yahoo Mail will crash one new emails are loaded in. I open the mailbox on another device and delete the new emails. Now reloading on the original PC has the page working again, as if one of the new emails caused it.
2. Messege boards - page XX will work fine but page XY crashes, not sure what it contains but maybe something heavier to download.

EDIT: additional info

Specs:

```
Intel i7-8700 CPU
32GB RAM
RTX 2070
Windows 10 64-bit
```

Usual performance when a crash happens:
[image: 2]

Installed software:

```
DisplayName                                                    DisplayVersion    Publisher                  InstallDate
-----------                                                    --------------    ---------                  -----------
7-Zip 22.01 (x64)                                              22.01             Igor Pavlov
BlueStacks 5                                                   5.0.200.1012      BlueStack Systems, Inc.    20210609

Mozilla Firefox (x64 en-US)                                    110.0             Mozilla
Mozilla Maintenance Service                                    89.0              Mozilla
Oculus                                                         <3                Facebook Technologies, LLC
Mafia II: Definitive Edition                                                     Hangar 13
OCTOPATH TRAVELER II Prologue Demo                                               Square Enix
SteamWorld Build Demo                                                            Thunderful Development
DisplayFusion                                                                    Binary Fortress Software
SteamVR                                                                          Valve
Rise of the Tomb Raider                                                          Crystal Dynamics
NARUTO: Ultimate Ninja STORM                                                     CyberConnect2 Co. Ltd.
Chess Ultra                                                                      Ripstone
Desperados III                                                                   Mimimi Games
Songs of Conquest                                                                Lavapotion
Sublime Text                                                                     Sublime HQ Pty Ltd         20210721
Vulkan Run Time Libraries 1.0.65.1                             1.0.65.1          LunarG, Inc.

Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Additional Runtime - 12.0.40664  12.0.40664        Microsoft Corporation      20210721
Patriot Viper M2 SSD RGB                                       1.00.00           Patriot Memory             20210507
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219    10.0.40219        Microsoft Corporation      20210622
ENE RGB HAL                                                    1.00.09           Ene Tech.                  20210507
ASUS DRAM_LIB                                                  1.0.22            ASUS COMPUTER INC.         20210507
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Additional Runtime - 11.0.61030  11.0.61030        Microsoft Corporation      20210721
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 X64 Additional Runtime - 14.32.31326 14.32.31326       Microsoft Corporation      20220925
Logitech G HUB                                                 2023.1.364056     Logitech
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Minimum Runtime - 12.0.40664     12.0.40664        Microsoft Corporation      20210721
HoMM III Compatibility Database
VMware Player                                                  16.1.2            VMware, Inc.               20210612
Microsoft Update Health Tools                                  3.70.0.0          Microsoft Corporation      20230126
Adobe Acrobat (64-bit)                                         22.003.20322      Adobe                      20230216
NVIDIA Graphics Driver 528.02                                  528.02            NVIDIA Corporation         20230121
NVIDIA GeForce Experience 3.26.0.160                           3.26.0.160        NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA Optimus Update 39.4.0.0                                 39.4.0.0          NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA PhysX System Software 9.21.0713                         9.21.0713         NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA Update 39.4.0.0                                         39.4.0.0          NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA FrameView SDK 1.3.8107.31782123                         1.3.8107.31782123 NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA SHIELD Streaming                                        7.1.31648965      NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA GPX Common OSS binaries (POCO, OpenSSL, libprotobuf)    7.1               NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA HD Audio Driver 1.3.39.16                               1.3.39.16         NVIDIA Corporation         20230121
NVIDIA Install Application                                     2.1002.382.0      NVIDIA Corporation         20230121
NVIDIA Backend                                                 39.4.0.0          NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA Container                                               1.37              NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA TelemetryApi helper for NvContainer                     1.37              NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA LocalSystem Container                                   1.37              NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA Message Bus for NvContainer                             1.37              NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA NVAPI Monitor plugin for NvContainer                    1.37              NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA NetworkService Container                                1.37              NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA Session Container                                       1.37              NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA User Container                                          1.37              NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA NvModuleTracker                                         6.14.25214.24630  NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA NodeJS                                                  3.26.0.160        NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA Watchdog Plugin for NvContainer                         1.37              NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA Telemetry Client                                        16.15.11.0        NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA Virtual Host Controller                                 3.05.0.1          NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
Nvidia Share                                                   3.26.0.160        NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA ShadowPlay 3.26.0.160                                   3.26.0.160        NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA SHIELD Wireless Controller Driver                       3.26.0.94         NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA Update Core                                             39.4.0.0          NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
NVIDIA USBC Driver 1.50.831.832                                1.50.831.832      NVIDIA Corporation         20230121
NVIDIA Virtual Audio 4.45.0.0                                  4.45.0.0          NVIDIA Corporation         20221215
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 X64 Minimum Runtime - 14.32.31326    14.32.31326       Microsoft Corporation      20220925
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Minimum Runtime - 11.0.61030     11.0.61030        Microsoft Corporation      20210721
Epilogue Operator version 0.9.1                                0.9.1             Epilogue                   20230104
ENE_EHD_HAL                                                    1.00.04           ENE TECHNOLOGY INC.        20210507
```

Device manager alerts:

[image: 3]

Comment: Start by restarting your computer and running Windows Update.

Comment: Please search thoroughly https://superuser.com/search?q=Aw+snap, share what you found and why it didn't help you.

Comment: @Sylvain the issue seems more tied to a specifi tab than the entire browser. I can have 20+ tabs open and one crashes but the others work fine. Added some examples to the main question.

Comment: Ah then it's different. You still have alerts in your devices, use SDI Tools ;-) Here I've for years 100/200 tabs permanently opened in a few windows (Firefox). Zero problem. I'd recommend Firefox / U Block Origin / NoScript / Ghostery. Then you're safe and it's FAR lighter. Ohhh nice find @Rubén !

Comment: Thanks for the find @Rubén, DSIM does fail with "Error 23:  Data error (cyclic redundancy check)." Samsung Magician doesn't show anything (that's my SSD) so I might have to go the Windows repair route.

Answer (score 0):

Following comments and with my *"Wet Finger In The Wind Methodology (c)(tm)"* it's possible the Network card crashes because:

- others PCs don't have this problem (so, not a router thing),
- on this one no Browser has access to the Net at that moment (they can't all have a problem).

Note it could be also a switch if your PC is behind a switch he's the **only** PC connected...

Or the WIFI, but I guess you're in LAN, with cables, and the cables are fine...

**When it's not working please check:**

- if for you're connected: Network Status?
- Device manager, see Network Cards, no yellow alert?
- Control Panel, Network connexions (or: WIN+R then ncpa.cpl), right click on your card, then Diagnostic?

**You may try to see if there's a more recent Network Card driver, from Windows.**

**Alternatively, you could check all your drivers with the free, P2P and powerful SDI Tools:**

https://sdi-tool.org/

It'll take time to update the index and packages.
It's really worth it - but concentrate on the LAN, please make sure you create a restore point.
Update its driver if it tells you so.

**It could also be due to a RAM module defect (I encountered this), and it's easy to check:**

- download memtest86 and set it up on an USB,
- boot on it a leave it some time to process the tests, maybe half an hour minimum.

**Of course, check everything else**, like using the Task Manager and File Explorer: disk space, enough memory, CPU normal or crazy at 100%, etc.

*If it's not the network card, at least you'll know what's working ;-)
I mean - diagnostic needs some sweat and perseverance. Good luck.*